# Screenshots Disappear

Tags: screen-capture

Asking this question again to continue the conversation from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8584343 .

If you read the above thread, they say either to paste a script into Terminal or change the screenshot options. First, I tried to change the screenshot options to the Desktop folder, it was already selected, but I selected something else, saved, then selected Desktop again. It didn't copy to Desktop. The only place I could find it was in the Recents folder. However, it can copy to other folders besides Desktop. The Terminal script only returns me to the original situation where the screenshot flashes for a second in the Desktop.

This is a stretch, but maybe save the screenshot to a folder other than Desktop, run an Automator script to filter then move screenshots to the Desktop. Would that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Back again. I tried my possible solution above, didn't work. The screenshot still disappears from the desktop.

Comment: 1. What version of **macOS** are you running? 2. In **Terminal**, what is the output of the following command?: `defaults read com.apple.screencapture location`.  -- If it's "`The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist`" that means it's the _default location_ of `~/Desktop`. 3. What **Folder Actions** are setup on your system? In **Spotlight** (**⌘Space**) type **Folder Actions Setup** pressing **Enter** when the **app** appear in **Spotlight**. What **Folders** have _actions_ attached to them, if any?